# SWRevealViewController open event

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I use SWRevealViewController as left slide menu in my App. I would like to detec when the menu is reveal in my ViewController. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to detect when views are loaded is to look at the console output. By default, the SWRevealViewController does not have console output for the different actions. However, you can modify it so that it does:

1) Go to SwRevealViewController.m

2) Navigate To The Code That Says:

```
 - (IBAction)revealToggle:(id)sender
   {
        [self revealToggleAnimated:YES];
   }
```

3) Add This Line Of Code Before The End Curly Brace:   `NSLog(@"A Side Menu Toggle Has Been Used`

This will print "A Side Menu Toggle Has Been Used" to the console output any time the reveal button is pressed. The same principles apply if you use the swipe gesture to reveal the side menu.